# The cardholder authentication value is invalid Authorize.Net AIM

Tags: authorize.net, 3d-secure

I am working on Authorize.Net AIM module on ZenCart. Recently we are integrating Cardinal Commerce for 3DSecure. The setup is already completed and we append the value of **x_authentication_indicator** and **x_cardholder_authentication_value** to Authorize.Net request. But response come with Code 3 and Sub code 117

I tried to use urlencode for the x_cardholder_authentication_value but still no luck

> **Response Code: 3.
>   Response Text: The cardholder authentication value is invalid.**

Below is the sending request array

```
    Sending to Authorizenet: Array
    (
        [x_login] => *******
        [x_tran_key] => *******
        [x_relay_response] => FALSE
        [x_delim_data] => TRUE
        [x_delim_char] => |
        [x_encap_char] => *
        [x_version] => 3.1
        [x_type] => AUTH_CAPTURE
        [x_method] => CC
        [x_amount] => 79.99
        [x_currency_code] => USD
        [x_card_num] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0002
        [x_exp_date] => 0120
        [x_card_code] => ****
        [x_email_customer] => TRUE
        [x_email_merchant] => TRUE
        [x_cust_id] => 25014
        [x_invoice_num] => TEST-33280
        [x_first_name] => Ashit
        [x_last_name] => Biswas
        [x_company] => Test Company
        [x_address] => Test Street Address1
        [x_city] => Miami
        [x_state] => Idaho
        [x_zip] => 33076
        [x_country] => United States
        [x_phone] => 5127965880
        [x_email] => abc@gmail.com
        [x_ship_to_first_name] => Ashit
        [x_ship_to_last_name] => Biswas
        [x_ship_to_company] => Test Company
        [x_ship_to_address] => Test Street Address1
        [x_ship_to_city] => Miami
        [x_ship_to_state] => Idaho
        [x_ship_to_zip] => 33076
        [x_ship_to_country] => United States
        [x_ship_to_phone] => 5127965880
        [x_description] => Baby's Breath Orange Filler
        [x_recurring_billing] => NO
        [x_authentication_indicator] => 05
        [x_cardholder_authentication_value] => AAABAWFlmQAAAABjRWWZEEFgFz+=
        [x_customer_ip] => 45.123.110.14
        [x_po_num] => Dec-21-2018 11:50:48
        [x_freight] => 0.00
        [x_tax_exempt] => FALSE
        [x_tax] => 0.00
        [x_duty] => 0
        [Date] => December 21, 2018, 11:50 am
        [IP] => X.X.X.X
        [Session] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        [url] => https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll
    )
```

Authorize.net should accept the Cardholder Authentication Value and if the Validation passed then cardholder authentication response code will be 2

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=117):

> **CODE**: 117
>
> **EXPLANATION**: The cardholder authentication value is invalid.
>
> **INTEGRATION SUGGESTIONS:** First, verify that the merchant's processor supports Verified by Visa and Mastercard SecureCode authentication values through Authorize.Net.
>
> - Chase Paymentech
> - FDMS Nashville (formerly FDC)
> - Global Payments (GPS)
> - TSYS (formerly Vital)
> - Wells Fargo (Verified by Visa only)
>
> Also, this error can be received in the event that a special character is included in the cardholder authentication value. To resolve this issue, the special character must be URL encoded.
>
> **OTHER SUGGESTIONS**: This code is applicable only to merchants that include the cardholderAuthenticationValue in the transaction request. The CAVV for a Visa transaction or the AVV/UCAF for a Mastercard transaction is invalid or contains an invalid character.

You will notice Cardinal Commerce is not on this list. That means you will not be able to use 3DSecure through Authorize.Net.